# Magento 2 :Add custom field on order create page admin

Tags: magento2, layout, orders

I want to add a date field right below shipping method on admin order create page

[image]

I tried searching but magento 1 solution shows up I'm new to Magneto

Comment: i believe this will help you to know the idea https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/236709/how-to-add-custom-block-in-admin-order-create-form-in-magento-2-2-5

Comment: will it be accessible in order save ??

Comment: @hukkuzalmi  did you find out more about if is saving the value against the custom attribute the order table ?

Comment: @hukkuzalmi, did you found any article or blog related to this ?