# Save Order attribute while creating order from admin

Tags: magento2

I have created order attribute
I also followed https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/236710/34850 & https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/302886/34850
which helped me creating custom field in admin create order form (phtml code below)

```
<input id="ponumber" name="order[ponumber]" value="" class="admin__control-text input-text" type="text" />
```

Now I want to save that value to order table for which I used below events
sales_model_service_quote_submit_before, sales_order_save_before & sales_order_save_after
But its not saving even tried printing logs, but logs didnt also worked on those observers

Can anyone please help me saving that attribute from admin create order form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found both method working, adding answer just if incase someone end up here

use event = sales_model_service_quote_submit_before
& in its observer

```
$order = $observer->getOrder();
$quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
$order->setPonumber($quote->getPonumber());
return $this;
```

or use event = sales_order_save_after
& in its observer

```
$order=$observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$params=$this->_request->getPost();
if($params && isset($params['order']['ponumber']) && $params['order']['ponumber']!='')
{
    $order->setPonumber($params['order']['ponumber']);
    $order->save();
}
```