# Insert a custom block into the $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.extra') placeholder in register.phtml

Tags: magento2, layout, template, custom-block, customer-registration

I want to insert a custom block into the `$block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.extra')` placeholder in the customer registration form - called in the `Magento_Customer::form/register.phtml` template file.

I have a custom block in my module that I'd like to insert into this placeholder to avoid overriding the `.phtml` file.

I've copied the `customer_account_create.xml` layout file into my module and replaced the code with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="customer.form.register.extra">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                   name="custom.block.name"
                   template="Vendor_ModuleName::my_custom_template.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I've also tried referencing by referenceBlock instead of referenceContainer but still my custom html is not appearing in the form.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get this to work? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the `customer.form.register.extra` is called in the phtml file, but never created by Magento in the `customer_account_create.xml` layout.

You have 2 solutions here.

---

The first one, which I recommend, would be to add your custom block to the `customer.form.register.fields.before` container instead (which is called by its alias `form_fields_before` in the template file).

In the template file, this container is called just before the `customer.form.register.extra` element, with no code in between. So there should be no difference for you to switch to this container.

You would end up with a layout file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="customer.form.register.fields.before">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                   name="custom.block.name"
                   template="Vendor_ModuleName::my_custom_template.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

*Note that it is not necessary to repeat the `layout="1column"` instruction on the `page` node of your XML file.*

---

Another solution, if you **really** need to use the `customer.form.register.extra` element first, would be to create it first in your layout file as a container, and add your custom block as its child.

You would end up with a code like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <container name="customer.form.register.extra">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                       name="custom.block.name"
                       template="Vendor_ModuleName::my_custom_template.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

The reason why I would not recommend this method, is because if in the future Magento or another module decides to create the `customer.form.register.extra` element, you would end up with this element declaration duplicated.

Comment: This is right answer...

Comment: @AmitBera, I got a reference from your answer (https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/236710/24801), I've implemented for same for this question its works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Magento Plugin Functionality.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register">
        <plugin name="Your_Module::Custom_Block"
                type="Your\Module\Plugin\Custom"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Add your layout here with the below condition

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Your\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;

class Custom
{
    public function afterGetChildHtml(\Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register $subject, , string $result, $alias = '', $useCache = true): string
    {
        if ($alias == 'customer.form.register.extra') { 
            $block = $subject->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('\Your\Module\Block\Custom')
        ->setTemplate('Your_Module::custom.phtml')
        ->toHtml();
            $result = $result . $block;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: When possible, I would avoid using plugins to add custom blocks when it can be done in the layout files. It adds more complexity when you want to look at the code or extend it, and is less readable than the usual XML instruction. If using a plugin was necessary, I would recommend using the `after` method instead of `around` ([which should be avoided when not required](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#around-methods)).

Comment: I've replaced around to after, now you can use this code.